# xdebug collects profiling data correctly except for one service

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug

I'm working on a large application built on Zend Framework. One of the service calls the application makes is very slow (15s) and I'm trying to profile php with xdebug to figure out what's slowing it down. However, xdebug isn't tracking any information for that service call. It works fine with all the other service calls, just not the slow one. Is there some sort of xdebug timeout that might be causing this, or maybe some other issue? I'm about to start peppering the code with microtime() and drop xdebug since it isn't working for the one service call I want to use it for. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest [profiling with XHProf](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/) instead? It is much easier to track down specific function calls with XHProf instead of cachegrind.

Comment: Excellent idea. XHProf is giving me much more useful data and doesn't seem to die in the slow service call like xdebug did. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim you're welcome (and to be honest, you sound like I did when I first tried it :))